# How to click on the button which is present in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

HTML code

```html
<a href="" ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding">RESUME</a>
```

**Problem:**
After clicking on link in our application,page is opening in new tab. In that new page i have to click on the resume tab(It is in middle of the page).

I have to scroll down and click that tab but am not able to click.

My code:

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,250);');
element(by.partialLinkText("RESUME")).click();
```

please help me

Comment: Is the new window on the same host? Otherwise the same origin policy prevents JS interaction between parent and child window.

Comment: @SebastianS S new window on the same host.

Comment: @raghavendrat isn't the answer given below working for you? If not let me know what's the issue you are facing. Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur It's working fine in chrome but not in firefox...I have to do with firefox please  help me

Comment: @raghavendrat what version of firefox and protractor are you using? What error do you get when you work with firefox? Can you please update them in your question?

Comment: @GirishSortur  I am using firefox 41.0.1 version and Protractor v0.10.22
    This is the error am getting : UnknownError: null value in entry: name=null

Comment: Are you sure of the versions that you are using? Kindly update protractor to the latest version available - `v2.5.1` and also update your selenium webdriver with that. There might be issues with the latest version of firefox browser, though your test cases work on it but few actions might fail. Try to downgrade your firefox browser to a lower version (`v39` probably) and check if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92342/discussion-between-raghavendra-t-and-girish-sortur).

Comment: @GirishSortur please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735725/not-able-to-run-my-test-cases-on-protractor-2-5-1-and-jasmine-1-3-1

Answer (score 5):

Switch to the new tab before even trying to click on the element. Later, wait until the element is present and is in clickable state using `ExpectedConditions` instance and [`elementToBeClickable()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) function in protractor. Once its in clickable state then perform a `click()` action. However `click()` function in protractor should scroll the page automatically without the need for you to scroll. Here's how -

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function(){
        var elem = element(by.partialLinkText("RESUME"));
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem), 10000)
        .then(function(){
            elem.click();
        });
    });
});
```

If the above code still doesn't click then do add in the scroll line before clicking it by resolving the promise that the functions return. Here's how -

```
var elem = element(by.partialLinkText("RESUME"));
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem), 10000)
.then(function(){
    elem.getLocation().then(function(loc){
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo('+loc.x+','+loc.y+');').then(function(){
            elem.click();
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

"After clicking on link in our application,page is opening in new tab"....
New Tab of browser?
Switch to the new tab first. Then click on that button.
Try browser.getWindowHandles(). It will return you a set.

Comment: @Girish this code is working fine in chrome browser not in firefox..Please tell me how to do it in firefox.  Thanks

Comment: @raghavendrat, which version of FF? is it compatible?

Comment: I upgraded to new version and now it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Please look into this issue and help me out of this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735725/not-able-to-run-my-test-cases-on-protractor-2-5-1-and-jasmine-1-3-1