# Not able to run my test cases on protractor 2.5.1 and jasmine 1.3.1?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

my conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      protractor.basePath = __dirname;

  },
  suites : {
  qa:   ['./specs/log_in.js','./specs/create_project_external_roles.js','./specs/create_position_us_roles.js',

 beta:   ['./specs/log_in_beta.js','./specs/create_position.js', './specs/candidate_status.js'],

  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000,
      allScriptsTimeout: 3000000,
      rootElement: "div",
      showColors: true
  },
  baseUrl: '',
};
```

Until last Friday evening, this worked fine. Suddenly, I am getting this error:

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window".

log_in.js

```
require(protractor.basePath+'/data/config_values.js');

describe('', function()
{
    it('', function()
    {
        browser.get(url);
        browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        expect(browser.getTitle())
        element(by.model('username')).sendKeys(user);
        element(by.model('password')).sendKeys(pwd);
        element(by.css('[ng-click="userLogin()"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        _current_url_beta = url+'/dash#/'
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(_current_url_beta);

    });
});
```

create_project.js

```
describe('', function()
{
    it('while clicking create button:', function () {

        element(by.css('span.icon-dir-down')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    it('while clicking create project button:', function() {

        element.all(by.css('[ng-click="openProjectModal($event)"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });
    it('Sending values to project name field', function() {

        element.all(by.model('data.projectName')).sendKeys(external_project_name)
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    it('while Clicking domain:', function() {

        element(by.css('a.chosen-single.chosen-default')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    it('Sending values to domain field', function() {

        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="Domain_chosen"]/div/div/input')).sendKeys("Information");
        browser.sleep(4000);
    });

    it('selecting domain', function() {

        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="Domain_chosen"]/div/ul/li[4]')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000)
    });

    it('while clicking external project button:', function() {

        element.all(by.css('label.btn.btn-default.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    it('sending values to external field:', function() {

        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="Company"]')).sendKeys("wipro");
        browser.sleep(3000);
    });

    it('selecting external company name', function() {

        element.all(by.css('a.ng-scope.ng-binding')).filter(function (a, index) {
            return index == 0;
        }).each(function (a) {
            a.click();});
        browser.sleep(3000);
    });

    it('Clicking Calender icon:', function(){

        browser.sleep(5000);
        element(by.css('i[ng-click^=open]')).click();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        element(by.css('[ng-click="move(1)"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(4000);
        element(by.css('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"]')).click();
        element(by.css("i[ng-show]")).click();
        element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.pull-right')).filter(function (button, index) {
            return index == 1;
        }).each(function (button) {
            button.click();});
        element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.pull-right')).filter(function (button, index) {
            return index == 1;
        }).each(function (button) {
            button.click();});
        element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.pull-right')).filter(function (button, index) {
            return index == 1;
        }).each(function (button) {
            button.click();
        });
    });

    it('Sending project Description to :',function() {

        browser.sleep(3000);
        browser.driver.findElement
        (By.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]/button')).click();
        element(by.id('Description')).sendKeys(des);
        browser.sleep(3000);
    });

    it('Clicking on create project button  :',function() {

        element(by.css('button.btn.btn-lg.btn-main')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);

    });

    it('Assertion', function(){

        browser.sleep(5000);
        var newProject = element(by.css('[title="new position"]'));
        expect(newProject.isPresent()).toEqual(true);
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });
});
```

create_position_us.js

```
describe('create position for USA', function()
{
    it('while clicking dashboard button:', function () {

        browser.sleep(5000);
        element(by.css('span.icon-stats')).click();
        browser.sleep(3000);
    });


    it('while clicking create button:', function(){
        element(by.css('button.btn.btn-main.dropdown-toggle')).click();
    });

    it('while clicking create position button', function(){
        element(by.css(('[ng-click="openPositionModal($event)"]'))).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    it('Sending position values:', function(){
        element(by.model('data.code')).sendKeys(pos_code_us);
        element(by.model('data.title')).sendKeys(pos_title);
        browser.sleep(3000);
        element(by.model('selectedProject')).sendKeys(select_project_name);
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.css('a.ng-scope.ng-binding')).filter(function (a, index) {
            return a == 0;}).each(function (button) {
            a.click();})
        browser.sleep(2000);
    });

    it('Clicking Calender icon:', function(){


        element(by.css('a.ng-scope.ng-binding')).click()
        element(by.css('i[ng-click^=open]')).click();
        element(by.css('[ng-click="move(1)"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(1000);
        element(by.css('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.css('i.icon-date.glyphicon')).click();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.pull-right')).filter(function (button, index) {
            return index == 1;
        }).each(function (button) {
            button.click();
            element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.pull-right')).filter(function (button, index) {
                return index == 1;
            }).each(function (button) {
                button.click();
                element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.pull-right')).filter(function (button, index) {
                    return index == 1;
                }).each(function (button) {
                    button.click();

                });
            });
        });
    });

    it('Sending No.of opening position:', function() {

        browser.sleep(2000);
        browser.driver.findElement
        (By.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[6]/ul/li/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]/button')).click();
        element(by.model('data.totalOpenings')).sendKeys('10');
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });

    it('Sending salary values:', function() {

        browser.sleep(5000);
        var salary =  element(by.model('data.ctc'));
            salary.isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    salary.sendKeys('500000');
                } else {
                   element(by.model('data.ctc')).sendKeys('500000');
                }
            });
        //element(by.model('data.ctc')).sendKeys('500000');
        browser.sleep(3000);

    });

    it('While Selecting location for US:', function(){
        browser.sleep(3000);
        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[9]/div/div/div/div/input')).sendKeys('los a');
        browser.sleep(3000);
        element.all(by.css('a.ui-select-choices-row-inner')).filter(function (a, index) {
        return index == 0;
        }).each(function (a) {
        a.click();});
    });

    it('Sending position description:', function(){
        element(by.model('data.description')).sendKeys(des);
    });

    it('While clicking analyse skill button:', function(){
        element(by.css('[ng-click="analyzePosition($event)"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });

    it('Sending skill name and selecting the skills:', function() {
        element(by.model('userInput.skillName')).sendKeys('java');
        browser.sleep(1000);
        element.all(by.css("a.ng-scope.ng-binding")).filter(function (a, index) {
            return index == 2;
        }).each(function (a) {
            a.click();
        });
    });

    it('Selecting Percentage:', function() {
        element(by.model('userInput.skillPercent')).sendKeys('80');
        element(by.css('[ng-click="addSkills()"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(1000);
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(250,0);');
        browser.sleep(2000);
    });

    it('Clicking on Preview button:', function(){
        browser.sleep(2000);
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(250,0);');
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css('button[ng-click="fetchMatches($event)"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(15000);
    });

    it('Selecting Monster:', function() {
        element(by.css('[ng-click="$select.activate()"]')).click();  // Autosource
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.css('a.ui-select-choices-row-inner')).filter(function (a, index) {
            return index == 0;
        }).each(function (a) {
            a.click();
        });
    });

    it('Selecting Carrer builder:', function() {
        element(by.css('[ng-click="$select.activate()"]')).click();// Autosource
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.css('a.ui-select-choices-row-inner')).filter(function (a, index) {
            return index == 0;
        }).each(function (a) {
            a.click();
        });
    });

    it('Clicking on Internal groups button:', function() {
        element(by.css('button.dropdown-toggle.ng-binding.btn.btn-default')).click();
    });

    it('Unchecking internal groups button:', function(){
        element(by.css('[data-ng-click="deselectAll();"]')).click();
    });

    it('Unchecking checkbox:', function(){
        element(by.css('li.list-group-item.ng-binding.ng-scope')).click();
    });

    it('Unchecking check box', function() {

        element(by.model('data.score_autosourced_resumes')).click();
    });

    it('Clicking on autosource button:', function() {

        browser.sleep(5000);
        element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-main')).filter(function (button, index) {
            return index == 1;
        }).each(function (button) {
            button.click();
            browser.sleep(15000);
        });
    });

    var newPositionLink = element(by.css('[title="Initial Status"]'));

    it('verify', function(){

        expect(newPositionLink.isPresent()).toEqual(true);
        browser.sleep(5000);
        var initial_count_before = element.all(by.css('span.badge.badge-default.ng-binding')).get(0).getText().then(function(text){console.log(text);})
        element(by.css('button[ng-click="autoSource()"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(10000);
});
});
```

config_values.js

```
pos_title = 'Python Developer'
project_name = 'AVR'
external_project_name = 'AVR tech'
select_project_name = "avr1"


url = browser.params.siteurl
user = browser.params.login.username
pwd = browser.params.login.password



des = "We're looking for a full stack web developer with between 2-5 years of professional experience.You will take on a central role in developing our products using Python and Django"
```

I am executing tests like this from terminal:

```
sudo protractor conf.js --params.siteurl="http://localhost.com" --params.login.username="raghavendra@gmail.com" --params.login.password="123456"
```

HTML code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="hireAlchamyApp" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: have you tried setting the "rootElement" out of the "jasmineNodeOpts" scope, as specified [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js)? Do you pass any value to --baseUrl? Can you add the html?

Comment: @flaviomeira10 Please see all the files and help me please. If i run each file individually it is working fine. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @raghavendra, `rootElement` has be specified on the top level of your config:

```
exports.config = {
    rootElement: "div"
},
```

Comment: @raghavendrat could you please show the test you are executing? How do you execute the tests? Thanks.

Comment: I posted all the files and execution steps also. please see all the files and help me please. From 1 week am facing this problem and am not able to fix this issue. please help me.

Comment: @raghavendrat what is your root element? Is it the first div? or something else? can you specify the exact path of root element so that protractor knows whats it checking for (root element should have a css selector syntax). Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur This is the html code : <html lang="en" ng-app="hireAlchamyApp" class="ng-scope">   please help me

Comment: @raghavendrat what is the `rootelement` you are looking for? Can you post that html in your question? As stated above, try to set the rootelement to something more definitive value. Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur I posted the html code, please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95523/discussion-between-raghavendra-t-and-girish-sortur).

Comment: @GirishSortur Please help me out of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715973/not-able-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-protractorplease-go-through-the-image

Answer (score 0):

@raghavendra t, as showed in your html, you must set your rootElement like this:

```
rootElement: '.ng-scope',
```

So, your config file would be like this:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
      protractor.basePath = __dirname;

  },
  suites : {
  qa:   ['./specs/log_in.js','./specs/create_project_external_roles.js','./specs/create_position_us_roles.js',

 beta:   ['./specs/log_in_beta.js','./specs/create_position.js', './specs/candidate_status.js'],

  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000,
      allScriptsTimeout: 3000000,
      showColors: true
  },
  rootElement: '.ng-scope', 
  baseUrl: '',
};
```