# Not able to click on hidden element in protractor?(Please go through the image.)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Here is the HTML code :

```
<li class="subdropdown">
                    <a href="" class="submenu-toggle">Create Position</a>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled dropdown-submenu" role="menu">
                        <li style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a ng-click="openPositionModal($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> New Position</a>
                        </li>
```

Here is my test case:

```
1) Move  the cursor on "Create position" toggle menu.
2) After the mouse hover, click on the "New position" menu list.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`browser.actions()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions), "by link text" and the "by partial link text" locators should help here:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

// open up the menu

// choose position
var choosePosition = element(by.linkText('Create Position'));
browser.actions().mouseMove(choosePosition).perform();

// choose new position
var newPosition = $('a[ng-click*=openPositionModal]');
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(newPosition), 3000);
newPosition.click();
```

Comment: It's not working and am not getting error also...I don't know why..please help me

Comment: I am not getting any error ...It is showing all the test cases are passed but it is not clicking the 'New position' ... through automation mouse hover is working but after that it is not clicking 'New position'.

Comment: @raghavendrat okay, changed the locator, please check if it works for you now. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with css, xpath, linkText, partiallinkText and cssContainingText locators ... It is showing test cases are passed but it is not clicking 'new position'.It is not showing any error also.

Comment: @raghavendrat okay, added an explicit wait to the code, does it help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code to click on an hidden element. May be it might help someone.

Import statement:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
```

Code:

```
const hiddenElement = element(by.id('hiddenIcon'));
browser.driver.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', hiddenElement.getWebElement());
```

Just change the `hiddenIcon` to the id of your element.